# Testing if an instance of a class receives a message when a class method that sends the message to all instances is called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, datamapper

Though correct, the title needs some explanation :)

I have this class:

```
class Character
  include DataMapper::Resource

  def self.tick_all
    all.collect &:tick
  end

  def tick
    # do stuff
  end

end
```

As you can see when `Character.tick_all` is called all its instances should receive the `tick` invocation. It works as exptected: when I fire up a console the stuff in `tick` gets done. But I can't get my tests to pass:

```
describe ".tick_all" do
  let(:instance) { FactoryGirl.create(:character) }
  it "invokes #tick for every instance" do
    Character.tick_all
    instance.should_receive(:tick)
  end
end
```

Failed example:

```
Failure/Error: instance.should_receive(:tick)
  (#<Character:0x00000002fa4e28>).tick(any args)
      expected: 1 time
      received: 0 times
```

Comment: The problem is that DataMapper will create a new in-memory instance to receive the tick. The ORM tends to spawn new in-memory objects, rather than re-use ones you have already loaded from the db. This can make not only testing, but also using, DataMapper, a little bit awkward if you need to get "messages" between objects.

Comment: Thanks, that explains a lot. So maybe I should test the desired behavior (test if the stuff that needs done is done) instead if tick gets called?

Comment: Yes that should solve your testing problem, but you should be aware that any object-to-object messaging system using DataMapper is going to have your objects talking to each other via changes to the data store, and many invocations of `reload`.

Comment: I switched from ActiveRecord to DataMapper for that very reason :) Would using Redis as my datastore solve this problem?

Comment: I don't know. Redis itself looks like it could support *single memory-instance (per process) equals single db-instance* semantics. But when accessed by an ORM, the properties of the ORM will usually be more important.

Comment: So you're saying it depends on the ORM? But in case of Rails and Redis there wouldn't be an ORM right? Not sure if I understand you completely.

Comment: I've not used Redis, so may have made non-useful comment there, sorry.

Comment: No problem, you've been a great help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expectation should be set up *before* the method call:

```
describe ".tick_all" do
  let(:instance) { FactoryGirl.create(:character) }
  it "invokes #tick for every instance" do
    instance.should_receive(:tick)
    Character.tick_all
  end
end
```

**UPD**: The code above doesn't work. What about this variant?

```
describe ".tick_all" do
  it "invokes #tick for every instance" do
    Character.any_instance.should_receive(:tick)
    Character.tick_all
  end
end
```

**UPD2**: Aaand one more version:

```
describe ".tick_all" do
  it "invokes #tick for every instance" do
    tick_count = 0
    Character.any_instance.stub(:tick) { tick_count += 1 }
    Character.tick_all

    tick_count.should == Character.count
    # or
    # expect{ Character.tick_all }.to change{tick_count}.by(Character.count)
  end
end
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. Probably because of what Neil Slater says (first comment on question).

Comment: Yeah, I think Neil Slater is right. What about the second variant?

Comment: It gives me a failure with a different message: `Failure/Error: Character.tick_all
       The message 'tick' was received by #<Character @id=2 @created_at=Wed, 08 May 2013 20:11:14 +0200 @updated_at=Wed, 08 May 2013 20:11:14 +0200> but has already been received by #<Character:0x000000049960c0>`

Comment: And I have a new version :)

Comment: It actually passes my tests if I remove `DataMapper.setup(:default, :adapter => 'in_memory')` (else it will throw an error saying aggregate isn't supported if the in-memory adapter is used). Not using the in-memory adapter makes my tests veeeryyyyy sloooowwww though...

Comment: Hmm, this is interesting. Thanks for sharing.